# Importing items from an Adobe Shared Library via Extendscript

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I am trying to mimic the process of importing items into the project pane in AE, but instead of pulling from a location on the user's computer, I'd like to be able to pull a select number of items from a shared Adobe CC Library that I've created, which would be shared with the user. I can't for the life of me figure out how to call the path to the shared cloud library, or if Extendscript can even support a connection to shared libraries.

In a nutshell, I'd like the user to be able to select a category from a dropdown in the script panel, say "Cars", for example, and then press an Import button which would comb the library for all items that fit in the "Cars" category, and import them into the project pane for further processing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use web sockets in extendscript to connect to the web. Have a look through the Javascript tools guide for sockets.

Comment: @stib thanks, sockets tipped me off in the right direction. Unfortunately, after some more research, it's also an application that requires a much more in-depth program than I am prepared to write at this time. For anyone else looking to make the connection to the shared libraries, I was able to get in touch with some folks at Adobe who suggested going the Adobe CC Files route (Adobe's version of Dropbox), as libraries does not currently support video files. Also Requires similar socket access, but overall is a more versatile platform for pulling assets into AE. Also suggested a look into CES.